# git checkout HEAD~2 ISSUE

Tags: git

I am on master branch and I did 2 local commits(not pushed) on top of commit which is pushed to remote.
I want to to get my local working master branch in sync with remote.So i ran the command

```
git checkout HEAD~2
```

I am successfully able to get my current working branch to 2 commits back and is in sync with remote master but locally i am seeing that i am working on "no branch"

```
gakaushik@L-MAA-00438612 /c/legacytxn/PayPalOneSpot/OneSpot ((db39c78...))
$ git branch
* (no branch)
  master
```

Because of this i am not able to do further pull/push operations associated with this branch.Can someone please tell why is this behaviour ?
I am new to git so kindly tell me if my understanding is wrong in anyway ?

Regards
Gaurav Kaushik

Comment: Do you want to keep your two local commits?

Comment: Have u tried git checkout master

Answer (score 2):

To get what you want,run this command:

```
git checkout -b newBranch && git reset --hard HEAD~2
```

Safe version:

```
git checkout -b `date +"%m-%d-%y-%s"`
git commit -am 'automatic';
git checkout master;
git pull;
git checkout -b newBranch && git reset --hard HEAD~2;
```

Comment: This needs to come with a giant warning that `git reset --hard` will blow away any changes in the working tree or index that are not committed. That said, it is the right tool for the job.

Comment: Thinking about what you said, insert an alternative version where the changes are stored in an additional branch